# Euler-Lagrange equations of 1D NLS with periodic external potential

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, dispersive-pde

I am trying to find the Euler Lagrange (EL) equations in order to find ODEs for the parameters $a(t), \xi(t), c(t), d(t)$.
Consider the following form: 
$$iu_t+\frac{1}{2}u_{xx}+|u|^2u=V(x)u \tag{1}$$ 
the ansatz (bright soliton)
$$u(x,t)=a(t)sech[a(t)(x-\xi(t))]e^{i(c(t)x+d(t)t)}  \tag{2}$$ 
and the potential $$V(x)=-A\cos(\frac{2\pi }{\lambda}x).\tag{3}$$
To find the EL equations I first consider the Lagrangian density 
$$ L=\frac{i}{2}(uu_t^*-u^*u_t)+\frac{1}{2}|u_x|^2-\frac{1}{2}|u|^4+V(x)|u|^2.\tag{4}$$ 
My question is how to proceed to find the EL equations?

Comment: Just forgot it. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP is essentially asking:

> *How do you get the [Euler-Lagrange (EL) equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Lagrange_equation) (1) wrt. the **complex-valued** function $u$ from the Lagrangian density (4)?*

Answer:

1. *The pedestrian/elementary-but-cumbersome way:* Vary (4) wrt. ${\rm Re}(u)$ and ${\rm Im}(u)$ independently, thereby obtaining 2 EL eqs. Rearrange to obtain eq. (1).
2. *The elegant way:* Vary the action
   $$ S~=~\int \!dt~dx~{\cal L}, \qquad {\cal L}~=~\frac{i}{2}(uu_t^{\ast}-u^{\ast}u_t)+\frac{1}{2}u_xu_x^{\ast}-\frac{1}{2}(uu^{\ast})^2  +V(x)uu^{\ast},\tag{4'} $$
   wrt. the complex conjugate function $u^{\ast}$, pretending that $u$ is an independent fixed variable: 
   $$ 0~=~\frac{\delta S}{\delta u^{\ast}}~=~\frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial u^{\ast}} 
    - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial u^{\ast}_t}-\frac{d}{dx} \frac{\partial {\cal L}}{\partial u^{\ast}_x}. \tag{1'}$$
   Eq. (1') gives the correct eq. (1) immediately! The justification for this method (1') is explained in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/89002/2451) Phys.SE post.